# Words regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I tried to write regex which checks if certain words are included in a string, i.e `one` or `two` would be those keywords. They can appear anywhere in the sentence.

String should not have any numbers, just letters. If it has no numbers and has either `one` or `two` I should return true.

Here is my attempt on that :

```
^([one|two]*\D*[one|two]*)$
```

But this matches empty String or any string without numbers. How can I adjust my regex a bit?

Comment: I have found this site to be an awesome tool for regexp: http://rubular.com/

Comment: Personally I prefer http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I'm using gskinner, but that is not what I asked. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

```
(?=^.*(one|two))\D+$
```

And here is the Java code:

```
    String input = "ajlfjalfd one jlafjldaj two jlkajfldja";

    final String REGEX_STR = "(?=^.*(one|two))\\D+$";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(REGEX_STR);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(input);

    return regexMatcher.matches();
```

Comment: The `$` in the end is redundant if passed to `matches` (and it *should* be passed to `matches`). If passed to `find` then it's broken because it's missing the initial `^`.

Comment: Can you please explain why it should be passed to matches? I used Pattern and Matcher.

Comment: And did you use `Matcher#matches` or `Matcher#find`?

Comment: So you are using `matches`. In that case the `$` is redundant.

Comment: You are right. Thanks! However I think we should keep `$` because, for example, you can copy the regex to other tools to check if it matches (I used Notepad++ for quick testing). Then keeping `$` will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work :

```
^\D*?(\bone\b|\btwo\b)\D*?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are used to match letters, not words. Also, the star symbol is used to mean 0 or more times, and it's only natural that it works with empty strings.

My advice? Find the simple solution to make it work. You could use two different regexes `/one/` checks if "one" is inside the string, `/two/` checks if "two" is inside the string. Combine the two, and you're good (not that hard, now, is it?).

Perhaps you would think that using two regexes is slow, but you would be using String#indexOf in the first place if you cared about performances in such an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about regex,

```
You can use contains() method for finding one and two.
e.g.  str.contains("one");


then you can use regex to find whether it contains digits or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try : `.*(one|two).*`

```
String s = "hi , there are only two objects";
        String pattern = ".*(one|two).*";
        System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
```